# discord.py covid module doesn't work AttributeError: Extra: no attribute 'allow'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, discord.py

I am trying to run the bot on a VPS machine, but I get a bug in the console related to the covid module, but on the computer everything worked as it should.

Error in console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dBot/bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    from covid import Covid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/covid/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from covid.john_hopkins import Covid as JohnHopkinsCovid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/covid/john_hopkins/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .covid import Covid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/covid/john_hopkins/covid.py", line 5, in <module>
    from covid.john_hopkins.models import CovidModel, CountryModel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/covid/john_hopkins/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import dataclasses
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/dataclasses.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .main import create_model, validate_model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 333, in <module>
    class BaseModel(Representation, metaclass=ModelMetaclass):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 326, in __new__
    cls.__signature__ = ClassAttribute('__signature__', generate_model_signature(cls.__init__, fields, config))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/utils.py", line 229, in generate_model_signature
    if config.extra is config.extra.allow:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/enum.py", line 146, in __get__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Extra: no attribute 'allow'
```

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def covid_hour():
    channel = client.get_channel(809881992367702117)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "Dane dot. COVID-19 w Polsce:",
        color = discord.Color.red()
    )
    url = 'API'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        raw_response = await session.get(url)
        response = await raw_response.text()
        response = json.loads(response)
        embed.set_author(name=str(f'{date}'))
        embed.add_field(name='• **Kraj**:', value=str(f"Polska"), inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Nowe zakażenia**:', value=str(f"{response['dailyInfected']}"), inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="dBot created by Diablo#4700")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        #await channel.send('``           ``')
```

Comment: is it a different version of discord.py?

Comment: The basic one and from what I remember is the newest.

Comment: This is not related to discord.py. Please add your code, it's hard for us to help you without any code snippets

Comment: Sure, i edit post.